# In an event sourced system, how do I get a current state of an entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

Let's assume I use Kafka as an event store and put there all the lifecycle events of an order. Now I need to get the current state of this order in my system in during some business process. What's the best way to get the state of this order? Some random ideas coming to my mind:

1. Before putting an event in the event store, store the current status of each entity in e.g. RDBMS (potential problem: scalability).
2. Load all events for that entity in memory and build the current state.
3. Apply CQRS architecture and use the view which is e.g. RDBMS, or even key-value store to quickly retrieve this order.

What's the approach you'd recommend?

Comment: Kafka is not meant to be an event store. It is only meant to transfer temporary events between producers and subscribers. And 2 is the right option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to all that I've looked into, you get your current state by doing a projection of your event history into the format you intend to use.  A projection is, in functional terms, a [left fold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).

That said, there are quite a few videos that cover this very topic when introducing the concept of Event Sourcing.  I'd search on youtube.  Greg Young does a really good job stating the concepts, but there's a number of videos that explore the topic in the context of your target language.

The mechanism you use to store your events isn't nearly as important as the ability to replay them into a structure.

One such example of a good resource is here:

https://youtu.be/AUj4M-st3ic

Answer (score 0):

> Let's assume I use Kafka as an event store

It is not at all clear that "Event sourcing", as understood by the CQRS community, is possible on Kafka.  The locking mechanisms required to ensure that the event stream is self consistent appear to be missing.

> Now I need to get the current state of this order in my system in during some business process.

"It depends" - in particular, it depends on whether you are obtaining a locked copy of the order that you will be modifying, or if you are obtaining an unlocked copy.  See Pat Helland, [Data on the Outside versus Data on the Inside](https://blog.acolyer.org/2016/09/13/data-on-the-outside-versus-data-on-the-inside/).

For the case where you are changing the order, you will normally be updating the event history, and to ensure correctness you'll need to be able to identify precisely where in the event history you are writing the event.  So your process will need to have some direct understand of the event history itself.  What people usually do is work with a cached representation of the entity that is built from the event, and kept synchronized with, the local event history, with the local event history kept synchronized with the durable copy in the event store.

In cases where you are not changing the order, it is common that you won't be working with the events at all, but instead a report/view/snapshot of the entity taken at some point in the past.  That could be something you build from the events themselves, but it is more likely to be an unlocked copy of a report taken from a document store or a relational database.